# Shapeless cannot provide implicit instance of Annotations.Aux

Tags: scala, generics, annotations, shapeless

I'm trying to simplify annotations extracting from case classes, but I still want to stay as generic as possible. So, I've created a simple type class that does nothing useful (for now), but it accepts two type params:

```scala
trait Show2[+A, -T] {
  def show: Unit
}
```

And I have a simple implicit function to derive instances of this type class:

```scala
implicit def genericEncoder[A, T, ARepr <: HList](
  implicit annotations: Annotations.Aux[A, T, ARepr]
): Show2[A, T] = new Show2[A, T] {
  override def show: Unit = println(annotations())
}
```

Basically, it's some kind of wrapper around `Annotations.Aux`.

To test I use a data class and annotation class itself:

```scala
case class ann(v: Int) extends StaticAnnotation
case class C(@ann(1) s: String, @ann(2) i: Int)
```

So, I'm expecting that something will be printed out after

```scala
val encoder = implicitly[Show2[ann, C]]
encoder.show
```

But I'm getting `could not find implicit value for parameter e: Show2[Main2.ann,Main2.C]`. When I use concrete type `ann` instead of generic `A` in `genericEncoder` it works, but it's not what I need.

Any thoughts, what am I doing wrong here?

[scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/E85rw649QJSBwlWlVLPMPw)

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work because of variances in the `Show2` typeclass (type parameters in `Annotations.Aux` are invariant)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks a lot for finding this out!

Comment: i added it as an answer, so could you pleaseaccept it if you found it as useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that it doesn't work because of variances in the Show2 typeclass (type parameters in Annotations.Aux are invariant)